# How to reset URLConnection in java?

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

is there any way to reset the connection,so that i can read from starting of the document?
It is a slow process that reconnecting to read from sarting,i want to read a file 20 times per second through http,is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLConnection is an easy but somewhat "dumb" class. I can suggest you to do it the Java way: instantiate a new URLConnection. ;)
Java is not really a language that encorages reusage of objects.

You can try resetting the input stream, see the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29) for more info, but I don't think it will do another GET. Who knows how the concrete implementation behind InputStream and OutputStream of URLConnections is done.

EDIT: I don't guarantee anything, but you could also try to disconnect() and then connect() again. Never tried it, see if it works.

Comment: how can i read from 0 continuesly if instantiate a new URLConnection?

Comment: Just keep instantiating new URLConnections and then read from the InputStream they provide. It won't be so slow and sluggish, since the bottleneck is probably the network, not the garbage collecting that you'll cause doing this. To do nice stuff with networking, use raw sockets, or some specific library. URLConnection and its concrete implementations are out-of-the-box stuff.

Comment: Moreover, if you're doing something like a "stress test" on your HTTP server, you can consider launching many threads. Since there's a lot of I/O and a little CPU, launching more threads can increase your throughput (new connections generated per second). To launch more threads just put your connection logic inside a runnable, then in a for loop create many threads running that runnable and join to all of them, later (don't join to every thread just after you start it, that will be like serializing)

Comment: This is the correct answer, but not the right explanation as to why. Abstracted away under the covers is a pool of connections - `HTTPUrlConnection` is "keep-alive" by default. When you create a new HTTPUrlConnection it will re-use a connection if it is available in the pool and hasn't timed out.

Comment: In short, `HTTPUrlConnection` *isn't* a "dumb" class. ;)

Comment: That's a clever implementation, I thought there was a dumb stateless HTTP connection maker that opened the connection and closed it for every GET.

Comment: currently the program lanches 20 threads per seconds,but it fails to finish it's work within 50 millyseconds,so I'm thinking of using same threads and reading from 0 again

Comment: Yeah, I have to retreat it. But I keep thinking that it's bit dumb as of its "interface" (I mean the semantics of the methods). That obsession of Java to encapsulate and generalize anything is a bit tricky sometimes. I would like to make some examples of misleading (even if correct) behaviors of URLConnection, but I've not the space here

Comment: Jinjavajin: so make any thread re-engage itself with a simple eternal while loop that starts from the beginning (new URLConnection(...)). You can kill the thread by changing some synchronized internal flag and putting that condition in the while loop

Comment: but it seems the reason for the process is being slow is the time taking to establigh a new connection and get a response from server

Comment: Uhm... Brian said URLConnection internals use a pool of connections, so it shouldn't be like this. Can you debug it with a packet sniffer, like Wireshark? You can always go raw sockets, which is totally under your control, and it's fairly easy with HTTP. However, under a certain limit, is normal for it to be slow. How many threads are you launching?

Comment: The default number of connections is 5, so at 20 threads it's going to have to be doing some new connections. I'd have to look and see if you can increase that.

Comment: launching 20 threads per seconds,giving each a task to download the 5 kb file

Comment: I looked :) So, it's a system property - `http.maxConnections`

Comment: Actually though - launching 20 threads at once you're really not going to get the benefit of this. The connection is only put in the pool once any data from the previous request has been drained from it.

Comment: I'm not an expert but java is so high-level I don't think it fits some specific needs like network debugging and stress testing. I would go raw sockets in java, or better some C/C++ low level solution.

Answer (score 0):

By default there is no way. If you really want this feature, you have write some code for that.
Write a URLHandler which gives a socket wrapper, that does buffering. Implement reset methods() as you like.

Thanks,
Ramesh