# How to clone an InputStream?

Tags: java, clone, inputstream

I have a InputStream that I pass to a method to do some processing. I will use the same InputStream in other method, but after the first processing, the InputStream appears be closed inside the method.

How I can clone the InputStream to send to the method that closes him? There is another solution?

EDIT: the methods that closes the InputStream is an external method from a lib. I dont have control about closing or not.

```
private String getContent(HttpURLConnection con) {
    InputStream content = null;
    String charset = "";
    try {
        content = con.getInputStream();
        CloseShieldInputStream csContent = new CloseShieldInputStream(content);
        charset = getCharset(csContent);            
        return  IOUtils.toString(content,charset);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error downloading page: " + e);
        return null;
    }
}

private String getCharset(InputStream content) {
    try {
        Source parser = new Source(content);
        return parser.getEncoding();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error determining charset: " + e);
        return "UTF-8";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to "reset" the stream after the method has returned? I.e., read the stream from the beginning?

Comment: Yes, the methods that closes the InputStream returns the charset it was encoded. The second method is to convert the InputStream to a String using the charset found in the first method.

Comment: You should in that case be able to do what I'm describing in my answer.

Comment: I dont know the best way to resolve it, but I resolve my problem otherwise. The method toString of the Jericho HTML Parser returns the String formatted in the correct format. It's all I need at moment.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

If all you want to do is read the same information more than once, and the input data is small enough to fit into memory, you can copy the data from your `InputStream` to a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).

Then you can obtain the associated array of bytes and open as many "cloned" [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)s as you like.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// Code simulating the copy
// You could alternatively use NIO
// And please, unlike me, do something about the Exceptions :D
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > -1 ) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
baos.flush();
    
// Open new InputStreams using recorded bytes
// Can be repeated as many times as you wish
InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()); 
InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

But if you really need to keep the original stream open to receive new data, then you will need to track the external call to `close()`. You will need to prevent `close()` from being called somehow.

#### UPDATE (2019):

Since Java 9 the the middle bits can be replaced with [`InputStream.transferTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream)):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
input.transferTo(baos);
InputStream firstClone = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()); 
InputStream secondClone = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: I fount another solution to my problem thar not involves copying the InputStream, but I think if I need copy the InputStream, this is the best solution.

Comment: This approach consumes memory proportional to the full content of the input stream. Better to use `TeeInputStream` as described in the answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107049/how-can-i-make-a-copy-of-a-bufferedreader).

Comment: IOUtils (from apache commons) has a copy method which would do the buffer read/write in the middle of your code.

Comment: @aioobe sorry to ask about such an old comment, but did you test the memory consumption, and if so, were your streams consuming at more or less the same time? The proposed solution (linked in your comment) uses `BufferedReader`, which is [backed by an array](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedReader.java.html), same as the [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.java.html) used in the answer above.

Comment: I'm not seeing how using `TeeInputStream` would improve memory consumption, except for the fact that the answer above uses a second call to `baos.toByteArray()` instead of using `PipedInputStream` for the second copy

Comment: If you do have Java 9, why not use `ByteArrayInputStream(input.readAllBytes())`?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi, [`InputStream.readAllBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()) will return an empty byte array after the first invocation (hence the need for an intermediate `byte[]` or `ByteArrayOutputStream`). On top of that [`ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray()) returns a copy of the original byte array, which may or may not be desirable (the code above creates independent stream "clones").

Answer (score 36):

You want to use Apache's [`CloseShieldInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html):

This is a wrapper that will prevent the stream from being closed. You'd do something like this.

```
InputStream is = null;

is = getStream(); //obtain the stream 
CloseShieldInputStream csis = new CloseShieldInputStream(is);

// call the bad function that does things it shouldn't
badFunction(csis);

// happiness follows: do something with the original input stream
is.read();
```

Comment: Looks good, but dont works here. I will edit my post with the code.

Comment: `CloseShield` isn't working because your original `HttpURLConnection` input stream is beeing closed somewhere. Shouldn't your method call IOUtils with the protected stream `IOUtils.toString(csContent,charset)`?

Comment: Maybe can be this. I can prevent from the HttpURLConnection be closed?

Comment: What is the `Source` class doing? Is it the call that is closing the stream?

Comment: @Renato. Maybe the problem is not the `close()` call at all, but the fact the Stream is being read to the end. Since `mark()` and `reset()` may not be the best methods for http connections, maybe you should take a look at the byte array approach described at my answer.

Comment: One more thing, you can always open a new connection to the same URL. 
See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807340/how-to-reset-urlconnection-in-java

Comment: For few inputstreams mark/reset is not supported such as InfalterInputStream

Comment: How to close this stream if it will not be used anymore?

Comment: `CloseShieldInputStream` constructor [is now deprecated](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html#CloseShieldInputStream-java.io.InputStream-). You can use static method `CloseShieldInputStream.wrap(is)` instead.

Answer (score 13):

You can't clone it, and how you are going to solve your problem depends on what the source of the data is.

One solution is to read all data from the InputStream into a byte array, and then create a ByteArrayInputStream around that byte array, and pass that input stream into your method.

Edit 1:
That is, if the other method also needs to read the same data. I.e you want to "reset" the stream.

Comment: I don't know what part you need help with. I guess you know how to read from a stream? Read all data from the InputStream, and write the data to ByteArrayOutputStream. Call toByteArray() on the ByteArrayOutputStream after you have completed reading all data. Then pass that byte array into the constructor of a ByteArrayInputStream.

Answer (score 11):

If the data read from the stream is large, I would recommend using a TeeInputStream from Apache Commons IO. That way you can essentially replicate the input and pass a t'd pipe as your clone.

Comment: No code answer....

Answer (score 6):

This might not work in all situations, but here is what I did: I extended the [FilterInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) class and do the required processing of the bytes as the external lib reads the data.

```
public class StreamBytesWithExtraProcessingInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

    protected StreamBytesWithExtraProcessingInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int readByte = super.read();
        processByte(readByte);
        return readByte;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) throws IOException {
        int readBytes = super.read(buffer, offset, count);
        processBytes(buffer, offset, readBytes);
        return readBytes;
    }

    private void processBytes(byte[] buffer, int offset, int readBytes) {
       for (int i = 0; i < readBytes; i++) {
           processByte(buffer[i + offset]);
       }
    }

    private void processByte(int readByte) {
       // TODO do processing here
    }

}
```

Then you simply pass an instance of `StreamBytesWithExtraProcessingInputStream` where you would have passed in the input stream. With the original input stream as constructor parameter.

**It should be noted that this works byte for byte, so don't use this if high performance is a requirement.**

Answer (score 6):

UPD.
Check the comment before. It isn't exactly what was asked.

If you are using `apache.commons` you may copy streams using `IOUtils` .

You can use following code:

```
InputStream = IOUtils.toBufferedInputStream(toCopy);
```

Here is the full example suitable for your situation:

```
public void cloneStream() throws IOException{
    InputStream toCopy=IOUtils.toInputStream("aaa");
    InputStream dest= null;
    dest=IOUtils.toBufferedInputStream(toCopy);
    toCopy.close();
    String result = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(dest));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

This code requires some dependencies:

**MAVEN**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**GRADLE**

```
'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```

Here is the DOC reference for this method:

> Fetches entire contents of an InputStream and represent same data as
> result InputStream. This method is useful where,
>
> Source InputStream is slow. It has network resources associated, so we
> cannot keep it open for long time. It has network timeout associated.

You can find more about `IOUtils` here:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toBufferedInputStream(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: This does not *clone* the input stream but only buffers it. That's not the same; the OP wants to re-read (a copy of) the same stream.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the solution with Kotlin.

You can copy your InputStream into ByteArray

```
val inputStream = ...

val byteOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
inputStream.use { input ->
    byteOutputStream.use { output ->
        input.copyTo(output)
    }
}

val byteInputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(byteOutputStream.toByteArray())
```

If you need to read the `byteInputStream` multiple times, call `byteInputStream.reset()` before reading again.

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/kotlin/how-to-clone-inputstream/

Answer (score 1):

Cloning an input stream might not be a good idea, because this requires deep knowledge about the details of the input stream being cloned. A workaround for this is to create a new input stream that reads from the same source again.

So using some Java 8 features this would look like this:

```
public class Foo {

    private Supplier<InputStream> inputStreamSupplier;

    public void bar() {
        procesDataThisWay(inputStreamSupplier.get());
        procesDataTheOtherWay(inputStreamSupplier.get());
    }

    private void procesDataThisWay(InputStream) {
        // ...
    }

    private void procesDataTheOtherWay(InputStream) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This method has the positive effect that it will reuse code that is already in place - the creation of the input stream encapsulated in `inputStreamSupplier`. And there is no need to maintain a second code path for the cloning of the stream.

On the other hand, if reading from the stream is expensive (because a it's done over a low bandwith connection), then this method will double the costs. This could be circumvented by using a specific supplier that will store the stream content locally first and provide an `InputStream` for that now local resource.

Comment: This answer is not clear to me. How do you initialise the supplier from an existing `is`?

Comment: @user1156544 As I wrote *Cloning an input stream might not be a good idea, because this requires deep knowledge about the details of the input stream being cloned.* you can't use the supplier to create an input stream fron an existing one. The supplier could use a `java.io.File` or `java.net.URL` for example to create a new input stream each time it is invoked.

Comment: I see now. This will not work with inputstream as the OP explicitly asks, but with File or URL if they are the original source of data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The class below should do the trick. Just create an instance, call the "multiply" method, and provide the source input stream and the amount of duplicates you need.

**Important: you must consume all cloned streams simultaneously in separate threads.**

```
package foo.bar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class InputStreamMultiplier {
    protected static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public InputStream[] multiply(final InputStream source, int count) throws IOException {
        PipedInputStream[] ins = new PipedInputStream[count];
        final PipedOutputStream[] outs = new PipedOutputStream[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            ins[i] = new PipedInputStream();
            outs[i] = new PipedOutputStream(ins[i]);
        }

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    copy(source, outs);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return ins;
    }

    protected void copy(final InputStream source, final PipedOutputStream[] outs) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int n = 0;
        try {
            while (-1 != (n = source.read(buffer))) {
                //write each chunk to all output streams
                for (PipedOutputStream out : outs) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            //close all output streams
            for (PipedOutputStream out : outs) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He wants to use the stream in one method to determine the charset and *then* re-read it along with its charset in a second method.

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing the [`@Anthony Accioly`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924132/5081877) with the example.

> [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html): Clones the `bytes-Stream` and provides number of copies as a List Collection.

```java
public static List<InputStream> multiplyBytes(InputStream input, int cloneCount) throws IOException {
    List<InputStream> copies = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    copy(input, baos);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cloneCount; i++) {
        copies.add(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
    }
    return copies;
}
// IOException - If reading the Reader or Writing into the Writer goes wrong.
public static void copy(Reader in, Writer out) throws IOException {
    try {
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        int nrOfBytes = -1;
        while ((nrOfBytes = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, nrOfBytes);
        }
        out.flush();
    } finally {
        close(in);
        close(out);
    }
}
```

> [Reader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html): Clones the `chars-Stream` and provides number of copies as a List Collection.

```java
public static List<Reader> multiplyChars(Reader reader, int cloneCOunt) throws IOException {
    List<Reader> copies = new ArrayList<Reader>();
    BufferedReader bufferedInput = new BufferedReader(reader);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    String delimiter = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedInput.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!buffer.toString().equals(""))
            buffer.append(delimiter);
        buffer.append(line);
    }
    close(bufferedInput);
    for (int i = 0; i < cloneCOunt; i++) {
        copies.add(new StringReader(buffer.toString()));
    }
    return copies;
}
public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int nrOfBytes = -1;
        while ((nrOfBytes = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, nrOfBytes);
        }
        out.flush();
    } finally {
        close(in);
        close(out);
    }
}
```

Full Example:

```java
public class SampleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "C:/Yash/StackoverflowSSL.cer";
        InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath) );
        
        List<InputStream> bytesCopy = multiplyBytes(fileStream, 3);
        for (Iterator<InputStream> iterator = bytesCopy.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Byte Stream:"+ inputStream.available()); // Byte Stream:1784
        }
        printInputStream(bytesCopy.get(0));
        
        //java.sql.Clob clob = ((Clob) getValue(sql)); - clob.getCharacterStream();
        Reader stringReader = new StringReader("StringReader that reads Characters from the specified string.");
        List<Reader> charsCopy = multiplyChars(stringReader, 3);
        for (Iterator<Reader> iterator = charsCopy.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Reader reader = (Reader) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Chars Stream:"+reader.read()); // Chars Stream:83
        }
        printReader(charsCopy.get(0));
    }
    
    // Reader, InputStream - Prints the contents of the reader to System.out.
    public static void printReader(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    public static void printInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        printReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    }

    // Closes an opened resource, catching any exceptions.
    public static void close(Closeable resource) {
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                resource.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```