# Clone InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

I'm trying to read data from an InputStream, which could either be a FileInputStream or an ObjectInputStream. In order to achieve this I'wanted to clone the stream and try to read the Object and  in case of an exception convert the stream to a String using apache commons io.

```
    PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
    TeeInputStream tee = new TeeInputStream(stream, new PipedOutputStream(in));

    Object body;
    try {
        ObjectInput ois = new ObjectInputStream(tee);
        body = ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            body = IOUtils.toString(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            throw new MarshallerException("Could not convert inputStream");
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not work as the program waits for incoming data when trying to convert the stream `in` to a String.

Comment: No. You can read the whole stream to a known source - say a `byte[]` or a `File` and then open **new streams** on that source to test. You cannot create a stream twice, this simply does not work. You _could_ try `mark()` and `reset()` but they may not be supported depending on the stream's source.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107049/how-can-i-make-a-copy-of-a-bufferedreader it should work using TeeInputStream and PipedInputStream of apache commons io

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already commented by Boris Spider, it is possible to read the whole stream e.g. to a byte array stream and then open new streams on that resource:

```
    byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);     
    InputStream input1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    InputStream input2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

    Object body;
    try {
        ObjectInput ois = new ObjectInputStream(input1);
        body = ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            body = IOUtils.toString(input2, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
       } catch (Exception e2) {
            throw new MarshalException("Could not convert inputStream");
        }
    }
```