# How to clone or copy a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bufferedreader

I'm creating an Android app which is going to read very large files, with about 1.000 to 40.000 lines, which takes quite a bit of time with a single loop. Therefore, I'm trying to create a multithreaded reader, which creates multiple threads, and each of them reads a specific part of the file, and then it puts all the small parts together in one big array or `String`.

I'm using a `BufferedReader` which loops through each line in the file, and store the line count.
Each time the loop run, I check if `lineNumber % LINES_PER_READER == 0` is true. If it is, I create a new reader thread, which should read the next `LINES_PER_THREAD`-number of lines in the file.

I wonder (because the files can be huge) if I can copy or clone the `BufferedReader` in any way, so that the new reader thread can just start reading from the line where it was created, because I already have a loop which is reading that line, instead of creating a new `BufferedReader`, read each line until I get to the specified line and then start reading the actual values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a copy of a BufferedReader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107049/how-can-i-make-a-copy-of-a-bufferedreader)

Comment: Side note: Are you sure the bottleneck is processing time and not IO bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't clone the BufferedReader. It will create trouble. Just send batches of lines to the individual processing threads.

Comment: I'll try this. It might be the IO bandwidth which is the problem. Then, this might not work...

Comment: If IO bandwidth is the problem, this wouldn't help, but not hurt much. Having multiple BufferedReaders would hurt more then.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion then, if the IO bandwidth is the problem?

Comment: No, if IO bandwidth is the issue, the best you can do is ensure you read the file no more than once, sequentially.