# Java: Read Binary File From JAR into Scalar, Not Primitive byte[]

Tags: java, jax-rs, binaryfiles

I have a binary file, in my jar, and I want to slurp its contents in binary mode, not into a string of characters.  Following [this example](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_read_a_binary_file_from_JAR)

```
private byte[] readBinaryFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    for (int read = input.read(); read >= 0; read = input.read())
        output.write(read);

    byte[] buffer = output.toByteArray();

    input.close ();
    output.close();

    return buffer;
}
```

It's pretty trivial, but the calling context is expecting and Object.  How do I pass this binary contents back to the caller, but not as a primitive array?  I am trying to deliver this binary data as a response to a web service using jaxrs.

Comment: A byte array *is* an object. It's extremely unclear what's wrong here... Also note that reading a single byte at a time can be pretty inefficient. It would usually be better to read blocks at a time, via a buffer. Oh, and either use a `finally` block to close each of the input and output streams... or a try-with-resources statement if you're using Java 7.

Comment: Excuse me, you are right, this is not a real question

Comment: Jon, can you point me to an example with a buffer?

Comment: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5924132/22656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jon notes, the caller should be just fine:

```
byte[] b = new byte[10];
Object o = b;
```

That works because as he points out a `byte[]` is an instance of `Object`.

Don't confuse `bytes` themselves, which are indeed primitives, with the array. All arrays are objects no matter what they contain.

So the caller should receive his `Object` and then send it back to his caller as `application/octet-stream`.