# How to get copy of InputStream?

Tags: java, android

I have gotten HttpURLConnection inputStream:

```
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Starts the query
    conn.connect();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
```

Now I want to produce two copy of this inputStream, one is used to store to a file, and the other one is used to parse, but after I stored, the inputStream is invalid to parse:

```
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            if (inStream.markSupported()) {
                inStream.mark(1);                   
            }
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                Log.d(TAG, "buffer: "+new String(buffer));
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outStream.flush();
            inStream.reset();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now how to get this inputStream entirely again?

Comment: do the same thing again

Comment: Does not help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923817/how-to-clone-an-inputstream?

Comment: @RC. It seems Android doesn't support CloseShieldInputStream

Comment: @PankajKumar It seems Android doesn't support CloseShieldInputStream?

Comment: This might be helpful for you, [How to clone an Input Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923817/how-to-clone-an-inputstream)!

Comment: @Adheep The CloseShieldInputStream is not an Android public class

Comment: My bad, I should have been more specific, check out this answer in that post
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5924132/1161998

Comment: Why don't you just parse the file after you created it from the inputstream ? Just create a FileInputStream on the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/ Commons-IO to get a `byte[]` of the data in the InputStream

```
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());
```

Then store the data in a file by writing it in an OutputStream, then do with the data whatever you want.

Comment: Do you mean I need add an extra jar to use this IOUtils?

Comment: Yep, commons-io binary jar, it does all the buffering and stuff for you, and your second code section can be removed and replaced with this one line

Answer (score 0):

> Now how to get this inputStream entirely again?

You do everything all over again, starting with `HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();`.

Or, you do two things with with bytes as you download them, rather than downloading them twice.

Or, you use the stream from HTTP to download to the file, then you read in the file for parsing.

Comment: The http server content changes every second, if get again, it is not the same content.

Comment: @VictorS: Then your options are the second and third ones in my answer: do two things with the bytes as you download them (more efficient but perhaps more difficult to code), or read in the file once you save it (easier but adds more disk I/O).