# How to clone an InputStream to allow reading from both streams ( original and clone)?

Tags: java, stax

I have an InputStream of which I read data to log it on the screen. Then, this data I wish to pass it to an StaxParser. However the staxparser doesn't know to feed continuously from string,but rather input stream.

So I would like to clone the same inputstream to read both from it.

Do you have any better idea? If not, how can I clone the InputStreams?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 4):

One way to "clone" the input stream would be the following:
Note that you need to handle the exceptions :)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > -1 ) {
    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
byteArrayOutputStream.flush();

InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
```

Also reference [How to clone an InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923817/how-to-clone-an-inputstream) for more options.

Answer (score 2):

You may store what you've read inside a `String`, then create an `InputStream` with it, and pass it to the parser :

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(srcString.getBytes());
```

Or, you have several ways to re-read from the same `Stream`, see here :

[Read stream twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501237/read-stream-twice)