# Spring ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and original POST payload

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, exception

I'm using `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` in a **Spring Boot**-based application, to capture errors in a single place and output a consistent error payload.

Everything works as expected.
`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` has a method `handleHttpMessageNotReadable` that can be used to "react" on a client sending an invalid message (in my case a JSON payload).

Again, everything works as expected. If a client `POST` an invalid JSON document, the code in the `handleHttpMessageNotReadable` is executed correctly.

Now, for monitoring purposes, I would like to log the invalid JSON. 
This is the code I'm using inside the `handleHttpMessageNotReadable` method, to get hold of the payload.

```
String line = null;
StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
try {
    BufferedReader reader = servletWebRequest.getRequest().getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
       jb.append(line);

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As expected, I get an exception because the stream has been already consumed by Jackson, for actually parsing the JSON payload:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request
```

What would be a **simple** approach to access the original POST payload?
Would it be possible to throw a custom exception which would contain the original payload (`MyException extends HttpMessageNotReadableException`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request body is converted from JSON into a java type by
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

If erros occur, the HttpMessageNotReadableException is thrown in the 
super class org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter#readJavaType

You can subclass MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, overwrite readJavaType(..) and try to throw your own exception or a customized HttpMessageNotReadableException there.

Most likely you will need to [clone the input stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923817/how-to-clone-an-inputstream), use one to try to deserialize the JSON, and another to use in case you need to throw an exception.
This may impact performance, but if thats not a problem, you may give it a try....

Comment: Thanks, your approach did the trick. I have created a subclass of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and overwritten the `read` method.

In order for the new Mapper to work in Boot, I simply declared as `@Bean` in my configuration, like so:


`@Bean
 public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        return new PayloadCaptureMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
 }`