# Spring ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and original POST payload on validation error

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot

I'm using `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` in a **Spring Boot**-based RESTFul application, to capture errors in a single place and output a consistent error payload.

Everything works as expected. A class that extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` can override `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` in order to "react" on a client sending a message that doesn't pass the validation.
Currently, validation is triggered by annotating the Request Body with the `@Valid` annotation.

Everything works as expected. If a client POST a JSON document which doesn't validate, the code in the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` is executed correctly.

Now, for monitoring purposes, I would like to log the invalid JSON. Obviously, the original `InputStream` is closed.

I solved a similar problem [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39250847/6564279) by sublcassing `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, but in the case in the link I needed to "hook" into the validation process and thrown a custom exception containing the invalid JSON document.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this *Filter* that wraps original *HttpServletRequest* with implementation that stores *InputStreams*`s data internally after it is read by container.
Here is the code:

```
public class RequestCachingRequestWrapperFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        filterChain.doFilter(new RequestCachingRequestWrapper(request), response);
    }

    public class RequestCachingRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        private final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        private final ServletInputStream inputStream;
        private BufferedReader reader;

        private RequestCachingRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
            super(request);
            this.inputStream = new RequestCachingInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        }

        public ByteArrayOutputStream getCache() {
            return this.bos;
        }

        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        public String getCharacterEncoding() {
            return super.getCharacterEncoding() != null ? super.getCharacterEncoding() : WebUtils.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_ENCODING;
        }

        @Override
        public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
            if (this.reader == null) {
                this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, getCharacterEncoding()));
            }
            return this.reader;
        }

        private class RequestCachingInputStream extends ServletInputStream {

            private final ServletInputStream is;

            private RequestCachingInputStream(ServletInputStream is) {
                this.is = is;
            }

            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                int ch = is.read();
                if (ch != -1) {
                    bos.write(ch);
                }
                return ch;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

It was posted here on SO some time ago, but I can`t find original anwser to give credit to.