# How to Set Request back in HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, inputstream, spring-restcontroller

I am able to get plain json request by using interceptor in spring rest controller for logging purpose. But once the json is read from inputstream of my  httpservletrequest, it become null in my controller layer. Is there a way to Set back the json in  input stream of my httpservletrequest in the interceptor laye? TIA.

Comment: I think you should *clone* your Stream. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924132/7176906)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because how the spring handle `HttpServletRequest`.
(once read inputstream from client inputstream will be empty.)

So, there can be a solution below.

1. Read bytes from inputstream (from client side)
2. Use the bytes data. (parse to JSON and use as your business logic)
3. Make inputstream from the bytes (to pass to reverse proxy)
4. Pass this to back-end.

Comment: Do you have any example to Set the input stream back to servlet

Comment: `byte[] byteArr = ...;` // 1.byte array from client side

Comment: // 2. using it first

Comment: `ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);`  // 3. byte array to input stream

Comment: `httpEntity.setContent(bis);` // 4. use this inputStream for setting a content of HttpEntity instance (i'm using apache library)